# Chinese characters in IntelliJ IDEA 12 overlapped

Tags: intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA to develop my Android project. I've encountered this issue when editing the string XML resource file today. The Chinese characters do show but just overlapped one by one. So basically all you see is a bunch of Chinese characters filled in and overlapped at single character space. Interestingly, when you try to delete those Chinese characters, you just delete the following XML closing tag but not the Chinese character itself...

Have tried copy/paste, same result. I am using the Windows 32bit version.
Can anybody help to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please [check this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97665) and linked issues for the problem background.

Right now when IDEA doesn't find the glyph to display in the current editor font that you have set in `File` | `Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts`, `Font`, it starts to search for the first font that has this glyph and finds some font with incorrect metrics that displays overlapping glyphs.

When this request is implemented, you'll be able to specify the order of fall back fonts so that some properly working font is tried first.

At the moment the solution is to change the editor font to the one that has all the required glyphs and proper font metrics (or to find and uninstall the font that is tried first and is displayed incorrectly, note that when running under JDK 1.7 IDEA will also try .otf fonts, not just .ttf, that is why the behavior is different in IDEA 11 defaulting to JDK 1.6 and IDEA 12 that runs under JDK 1.7).

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder I'll definitely try this solution you provided.